# Starting a ASP.NET restful webservice on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, iis

I have developed a restful web service using ASP.NET, and while using the Visual Studio environment, it worked like a charm with IIS Express. The service itself is a complementary feature and will have to run on every machine on which our product is installed.

I have therefore created a new directory *webservice*, which holds the **web.config** and the **Global.asax** file, as well as a directory *bin*, which holds the **RestulWebservice.dll** file.

[image: directory]

I then have setup a new web page on the IIS, rooting at *C:\inetpub\wwwroot*. The web page itself is hosting a web application, based in *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RestfulWebservice* (which holds the files described above).

[image]

However, if I startup the IIS and visit `http://localhost:80/RestfulWebservice`, all I am getting is an error 403.14, stating that I may not inspect the contents of this folder unless I allow IIS to do so. If I choose to allow this, I am simply presented with the contents of the folder, not the service itself.

If I try to access a resource of the restful web service directly (i.e. `http://localhost:80/RestfulWebservice/Home`, I get a direct 404.0 error, telling me that the resource does not exist)

What am I doing wrong here, it can impossibly be **this** hard to get a compiled library ASP.NET web service to run on the IIS, it works like a charm on IIS express.

Comment: Sounds like you may not have ASP.NET enabled for the website. Double check your IIS configuration.

Comment: Did you manually copy? Can you try 'publish' by right clicking the webservice project in visual studio?

Comment: I tried to manually copy the contents as well as a real publishing. Both did not work. The ASP.NET settings are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```